# Inconsistent line endings in SSIS Flat File import

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have a large, pipe delineated text file with no text qualifiers, and it looks like whatever spit out this file accidentally spit out false "LF" markers in the last column every few hundred rows.
The last column is a descriptive column, and It is not text qualified in any way like it should be.
file looks similar to this:

```
id|data|data|data|data|Description[LF]
id|data|data|data|data|Description[LF]
id|data|data|data|data|Description[LF]
id|data|data|data|data|Descr[LF]
iption[LF]
id|data|data|data|data|Description[LF]
Id|data|data|data|data|Description[LF]
id|data|data|data|data|Descripti[LF]
on[LF]
id|data|data|data|data|Description[LF]
id|data|data|data|data|Description[LF]
id|data|data|data|data|Description[LF]
id|data|data|data|data|Description[LF]
id|data|data|data|data|D[LF]
escription[LF]
```

I'm pretty new to SSIS and SQL in general, Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: You're going to want to fix the file, likely by hand but you could probably hack it together in a preprocessing script task. SSIS doesn't deal well with irregular lines like that

Comment: An alternative to 'by hand' is to import the file into a table with one large-enough VarChar field (one record per file line).  You may be able to better piece it together programatically in t-sql.

Comment: If the last line is a description column, it probably was user-input where line feeds could be a part of the input.   That column needs to be delimited, or the Line Feeds inside the description need to be removed.   If you have any influence at all with the creator of the file, I would insist that they implement one of those two steps, and tell them it's absolutely necessary in order for you to be able to import the file.

Comment: This is a major companies DB, and I have no pull with the creator, however I managed to fix it in Notepad++. There was a unique 8digit number for the ID, followed immediately by a blank space. So I deleted every line feed from the file and then used a find and replace regular expression: (\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d[[:blank:]]) replaced with \r\n\1

Answer (score 1):

I did actually find a way to fix it in Notepad++, because I don't know C# and I don't know SSIS well enough..

The ID was 8 Digits long, and followed by 7 Blank spaces. That was absolutely unique to this file.

In notepad++ I used (Find Extended) to search and replace "\n"(LF) with nothing

then I used the this expression for find:

```
(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d[[:blank:]][[:blank:]][[:blank:]][[:blank:]][[:blank:]][[:blank:]][[:blank:]])
```

to find all 8 digit numbers with 7 trailing spaces, and for replace, used this:

```
\r\n\1
```

to put a [CR][LF] in front of those 8 digit numbers.

Lo and behold it worked! 
But either way.. My boss contacted the client and is requesting a better file. Now I get kudos, and we get proper data. Thanks for the advice all!

Comment: Good thing it's a one off, and not an every day data feed

Comment: That's what I'm learning. It's a monthly feed. It will be corrected next time though

Comment: In that case, you can add regex processing to the file, but you'd need to load it in as one big string, re-delineate it, and then read that one element into a new structure. I think you could do it in just raw SQL with as a bunch of nested SELECT statements and string replace.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to take a guess, I would say that this is occurring because of how the file is created... you are probably having data that just happens to include certain special characters which are being incorrectly interpreted as a Line Feed.

Check this [site](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm) to see if the data within your problem lines match any of these encodings. If this is the case then ultimately you have two options available:

1) Create some elaborate and complicated [ETL process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) to detect and correct the file data before you process it. This is inadvisable as it will be a major pain to create and maintain.

2) Try changing the way this file is produced. Most text export wizards will allow you to place quotes (") around text items so that your import process can quickly detect something as a text block as opposed to a series of encoded characters to interpret.